# Копирование файлов powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Нужно копировать бэкапы базы данных с виндовой машины. Машина не в домене, и копировать нужно на шару. Я попробовал составить скрипт такой:

```
$password = Get-Content C:\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$login = "workgroup\root"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($login,$password)
New-PSDrive -Name source -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\BIOSRV\DB-backups -Credential $cred_bio | Out-Null
New-PSDrive -Name target -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\file-srv\backup01 | Out-Null


Copy-Item -Path source:\'*'.sql -Confirm -Credential $cred_bio -Destination target: -Force
Remove-PSDrive source
Remove-PSDrive target
```

И выдает он мне вот такую ошибку:
The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials

я на powershell не писал никогда

Comment: Тогда присмотрись к `robocopy`.

Comment: @donRumata А Robocopy уже поддерживает логин/пароль?

Comment: Версия Powershell какая?

Answer (score 0):

Я не помню, с какой версии Powershell поддерживает credentials в операциях с сетевыми путями, мне раньше помогал небольшой "лайвхак" - подключить расшаренный ресурс с нужным логином/паролем, а затем, если не нужно, отключить. Тогда нужные credentials  "закэшируются" на время сессии:

```
net use \\удаленная_машина\C$ $password /USER:$username
# Делаем всё, что нужно
net use \\удаленная_машина\C$ /delete
```

Отмечу, однако, что иногда такой подход требует ручного ввода имени пользователя/пароля в всплывающем окне. У меня такого "безобразия" никогда не было, но кто-то из знакомых, кто пользовался данным методом, упоминал.

Что касается вашего скрипта, меня смущает: 
то **$cred**, то **$cred_bio**
но если дело не в этом, то другое: два раза вызываете credentials, возможно, это и не нравится системе. Конкретнее: не используйте их при вызове
   Copy-Item. Что-то типа:

```
$Source = "Z:\"
$Dest = "\\file-srv\backup01"
New-PSDrive -Name Z: -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\BIOSRV\DB-backups" -Credential $cred
Copy-Item $Source -Destination $Dest
```

P.S. Как насчёт [Bittransfer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/bits/using-windows-powershell-to-create-bits-transfer-jobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

```
$password = Get-Content C:\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$login = "workgroup\root"    Import-Module bitstransfer
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($login,$password)
    $sourcePath = \\BIOSRV\DB-backup\*.sql
    $destPath = \\file-srv\backup01
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Credential $cred
```